# Which OS should choose to generate certificates to configure a IoT Edge device as Transparent Gateway?

Tags: azure, apache-nifi, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to configure Edge device as a transparent gateway. But I am new to the concept.
I am using different machine to generate the certificates and later I will copy them to my Edge device.
I am following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-transparent-gateway?view=iotedge-2020-11) to generate certificates.

My question is:
The edge device is Linux based and my development machine is Windows. So which steps should I follow to generate the certificates (and if I follow Windows steps to generate the certificates, will it work for Linux based IoT edge device?)

How can I copy the certificates from development machine to IoT edge device (which is VM Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS)?

Any help would be really great.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your IoT Edge device is Linux based, you should follow the steps for Linux machine to configure the certificate.

Follow the steps given in [Manage certificates on an IoT Edge device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-manage-device-certificates?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=linux) and follow the complete tutorial for complete development.